# Catch ID (Event Handler) from different buttons in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created an jQuery function that generates links and write it in an div container in html

The Result is:

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">

<a id="crumb1">Crumb1</a> 
<a id="crumb2">Crumb2</a>

</div>
```

Yet I want to get an alert if some of the dynamically created links was clicked. In this alert  I want to show the clicked ID. How can i do this? Can i bind a click() event to the div-Tag which alerts me the clicked ID of the -Tag?

Thx for help me

Comment: here are so many answers already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following either in a script element at the end of the document body or in a document ready handler:

```
$("#breadcrumbs").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a [event delegatio](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)n based click handler since the target elements are created dynamically.

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#breadcrumbs').on('click', 'a', function () {
        alert(this.id)
    })
})
```

Inside the click handler `this` will refer to the targeted element(in this case the anchor element), so you can get the `id` using `this.id`